# How to find all columns from all tables that match a pattern

Tags: sas, metadata, proc-sql

I have a series of tables in SAS, and I'd like to list all the tables and their columns where the table name is `like "abc%"` (i.e. all tables that start with the string "abc")

I'd rather use proc sql, if possible.

Comment: Check out the dictionary tables, they have all the info you need in them. There are some worked examples here http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/070-30.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Zfunk alludes to in comments, this is possible through `dictionary.columns`.

```
proc sql;
  select name 
    from dictionary.columns
    where libname='MYLIB' and memname like 'ABC%';
quit;
```

Names (table/libnames) are upper case almost always in the dictionary tables.  LIBNAME is obvious, MEMNAME is table name, NAME is column name.  There's a ton of other stuff there, create a table with `select *` to see all of it.

Other useful tables also exist; for an idea of the full list, look in `SASHELP` in the Vs.  `SASHELP.VCOLUMN` = `dictionary.columns`, and most of the others are identical other than removing a V and adding an s.  [Kirk Laffler's SUGI 30 paper](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/070-30.pdf) that ZFunk referred to in comments is also an excellent starting place to investigate this.

Comment: This, along with Zfunk's comment totally worked. Thanks for all your help!